# Inserting Rows for some missing columns in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

> My Dataframe looks like this and i have to insert a few rows

```
 Date     AccessType    PrePaidSubsRev
 2013-11-01  1    584190
 2013-11-01  2    0
 2013-11-02  1    800020
 2013-11-02  2    0
 2013-11-03  1    705800
 2013-11-03  2    0
 2013-11-04  1    699930
 2013-11-04  3    0
 2013-11-04  2    0
 2013-11-05  1    963270
 2013-11-05  3    0
 2013-11-05  2    0
 2013-11-06  1    874530
 2013-11-06  3    0
 2013-11-06  2    0
 2013-11-07  1    886005
 2013-11-07  2    0
 2013-11-08  1    1209300
 2013-11-08  3    0
 2013-11-08  2    0
 2013-11-09  1    762560
 2013-11-09  2    0
 2013-11-10  1    489730
 2013-11-10  2    0
```

1. For dates where the accesstype 3 is missing i have to insert rows
   with the same date and accesstype as 3 and PrePaidSubsRev value as 0 .

   If someone has any idea please go ahead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> group = df.groupby(['Date','AccessType']).sum()
>>> temp = group.unstack()
>>> temp = temp.replace('nan',0)
>>> temp = temp1.stack()
>>> df = temp.reset_index()
```

This part worked for me..Thanks

Comment: Hi i tried it out in Python 2.6.6 the replace command does not work there ,but in python 2.7 it works fine ..any help please feel free

Comment: The part  temp = temp.replace('nan',0) is not working ,its not replacing nan with 0 in the groupby object and thanks for the response Roman